# Underline from end of the word till value in html

Tags: html, css

In a mail html format, I have to use 2 `<td>` in one table; one of them is sentence, the other one is value. I don't know how to make underline from end of the sentence to next value.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: You want an underline *between* cell values? It would help if you'd describe your intention.

Comment: yes i want to underline between cell values.

Comment: Why not underline each individually?